# DeviceInformation.GetGlyphThumbnailAsync always get dark theme thumbnail

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am newbie to UWP, try to access a thumbnail, I am getting dark theme image. App.xaml requested theme is light

```
.cs
     DeviceThumbnail deviceThumbnail = await DeviceInformation.GetGlyphThumbnailAsync();
                var glyphBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
.xaml
     <Image Source="{x:Bind GlyphBitmapImage, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="UniformToFill" RequestedTheme="Light" Grid.Column="0" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Please help me to resolve.

if windows 10 light theme  I can see setting image as
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most system images only exist as pure white images on a transparent background. This is what you are seeing when you call `GetGlyphThubnailAsync()`.

Because these images contain only a single color and an alpha channel they are easy to manipulate if you need a different version, such as in a different color.

The easiest way to change the returned thumbnail to be black on white is to use the `Invert()` method from [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx).
Assuming this XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="GlyphImage" />
<Image x:Name="InvertedGlyphImage" />
```

they could be populated like this:

```
var thumbnail = await deviceInfo.GetGlyphThumbnailAsync();

var regular = new BitmapImage();
regular.SetSource(thumbnail);

GlyphImage.Source = regular;

var wb = new WriteableBitmap(regular.PixelWidth, regular.PixelHeight);
var newWb = await wb.FromStream(thumbnail);

InvertedGlyphImage.Source = newWb.Invert();
```

and would produce output like this:

[image]

I also noticed that you set the `RequestedTheme` property on the Image you are using for display. Note that this property tells a FrameworkElement which system style to use when rendering its UI. This would not have any impact on the bitmap you display.